# jqGrid - How can i track the speed of local operations

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have received as a assignment create 2 applications, one optimized and one unoptimized and i am using free jqGrid to display the data from DB.

I have successfully created both but i would like to track the speed at witch the local operations are done(paging,search,sorting).

I have tried to set up events for each button that triggers the operations, but they dont seem to trigger... i was wondering if there is something better that is built into jqGrid that i could use or a advice that would help me resolve this.

My jqGrid code goes like this:

```js
$(function () {
    var colModelSettings = [
        {name:'id', label:'id',key: true, hidden: true, width:10,sorttype:'number',editable: true},     
        {name:'judet',label:'Judet',width:70,   align: 'center',editable:true},
        {name:'localitate',label:'Localitate',width:80,editable:true,searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq','bw','ew','cn']},align: 'center'},
        {name:'tipStrada',label:'tipStrada',editable:true,searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq','bw','ew','cn']},width:100,align: 'center'  },
        {name:'denumire',label:'denumire',editable:true,width:100,searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq','bw','ew','cn']},align: 'center'},
        {name:'cod',label:'cod',width:90,editable:true,align: 'center'}
        ];
    var beforeEvent = 0;    
    $("#gridAdrese").jqGrid({
        pager: $("#pagerGrid"), 
        url: "/UnoptimizedProject/rest/fetchData",
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "POST",
        loadonce: true,
        forceClientSorting:true,
        height: window.innerHeight-250,
        sortname: 'id',
        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
        serializeGridData: function (postData) {
            if (postData.searchField === undefined) postData.searchField = null;
            if (postData.searchString === undefined) postData.searchString = null;
            if (postData.searchOper === undefined) postData.searchOper = null;
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        },
        rowNum: 5000,
        viewrecords: true,
        loadComplete: function(){
            if(beforeEvent !== undefined){
                var afterEvent = new Date().getTime();
                console.log(afterEvent- beforeEvent);
                beforeEvent = 0;
            }
        },
        sortorder: 'asc', 
        caption:'Coduri Postale Neoptimizat' ,
        autowidth: true,
        colModel: colModelSettings,
    });
    $("#gridAdrese").jqGrid('navGrid', "#pagerGrid", {edit:false, add:false, del:false, save:false, cancel:false, search:true, searchtext: 'Search', refresh: false});

    $("#jqgh_gridAdrese_judet, #jqgh_gridAdrese_localitate, #jqgh_gridAdrese_tipStrada, #jqgh_gridAdrese_denumire, #jqgh_gridAdrese_cod ").on("click",function(){
        beforeEvent = new Date().getTime();
        console.log("Sorting");
    })
    $("#fbox_gridAdrese_search").on("click",function(){
        beforeEvent = new Date().getTime();
        console.log("searching");
    });

    $("#next_pagerGrid , #last_pagerGrid, #prev_pagerGrid, #first_pagerGrid").on("click",function(){
        beforeEvent = new Date().getTime();
        console.log("paging");
    })
});
```

Comment: You write about "2 applications, one optimized and one unoptimized". What is "optimized"? Only the response time from the `url`? You use `loadonce: true, forceClientSorting:true`. It means that sorting, paging and search will be done **locally** by jqGrid. Thus the time of sorting, paging and search will be the same with optimized and unoptimized backend.

Comment: The optimized and unoptimized differences are mostly on the backend and technologies used there. The optimized application makes all operation like search, sort, pagination, on the backend and the unoptimized app does it locally.

Comment: You can remove `id` coulumn, which is not needed at all. You can remove all `label` if the value of `label` is the same as the value of `name` (for example `name:'tipStrada',label:'tipStrada'`, `name:'denumire',label:'denumire'`, ...)

Comment: The code which you posted use `loadonce: true` with `url: "/UnoptimizedProject/rest/fetchData"`. It means that searching, sorting and pagination will be done locally. Probably you have another code in your real application.

Comment: Look at [the code](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-4000-20-free-jqgrid.htm), which displays probably what you need.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was not on my computer. That is the actual code i am using and is working as intented, to have search, sorting and pagination done localy. The demo you shared is exactly what i was looking for, thank you. If you can, post a answer so i can accept it. Thanks, Oleg!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do about the following:

```js
var startTime, measureTime = false, timeInterval,
    startMesure = function () {
        startTime = new Date();
        measureTime = true;
    };

startMesure();
$("#gridAdrese").jqGrid({
    url: "/UnoptimizedProject/rest/fetchData",
    ...
    onSortCol: function () {
        startMesure();
    },
    onPaging: function (pgButton, options) {
        //if (pgButton === "records") {
            startMesure();
        //}
    },
    searching: {
        closeAfterSearch: true,
        closeAfterReset: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        searchOnEnter: true,
        beforeSearch: function () {
            startMesure();
            return false; // allow filtering
        },
        onSearch: function () {
            startMesure();
        },
        onReset: function () {
            startMesure();
        },
    },
    loadComplete: function () {
        if (measureTime) {
            timeInterval = new Date() - startTime;
            setTimeout(function () {
                alert("Total loading time: " + timeInterval + "ms\nFull time: " +
                    (new Date() - startTime));
            }, 50);
            measureTime = false;
        }
    }
}).jqGrid("filterToolbar").jqGrid("navGrid");
```

We reset `startTime` with respect of `startTime = new Date();` to the current time at the beginning of sorting, paging or filtering.